# Context property of SignalR Hub does not give me Http Context by using GetHttpContext method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

In my application I plan to use SignalR in order for the backend code to send messages to the logged in user based on the conditions that arise on the server.
In particular I want the SignalR to call methods on the JS client whenever something happens on the backend. This could be periodic calculations happening on the backend that suddenly pass a threshold and I need to invoke something on the JS client for a particular User. The particular User is the key element here. Only the User that should know about this.
I'm assuming this should be very simple with SignalR but I have some problem understanding the way to implement this. My solution is as follow;

- Each time a user logs in, I create a SignalR Group and add that user to that group.
- Each time a user logs out, I remove them from the Group. (I don't know if I can also delete the Group itself)
- Now each time something happens on the back end, I use SignalR to push information to a particular User that needs to know about that event by calling a JS client method and sending to the group with the name equal to the Name Identifier of the user of interest.

So to apply this solution, I need to get the information about the User that just logged in inside the C# Hub in order to create the group and join him.

Now my problem is, how to access the information that I need from the User that logs in to the application in the C# Hub . I'm interested in the User Name Identifier of course. I have been thinking that the Context Property in the Hub should give me the information that I need (This is my understanding of the MS Docs) but I cannot make it to work. Please study below code.

```
// As soon as a User logs in, below method fires. I try to get the information 
// in here but no success        

public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
      var CID = Context.ConnectionId;   // this gives a unique connection ID
      var user = Context.User; // This returns nothing
      var userID = Context.UserIdentifier; // This returns nothing
      var httpContextObject = Context.GetHttpContext(); // This returns nothing
      await base.OnConnectedAsync();
}
```

When I call other methods in the C# Hub from JS the method is fired and
information is passed but I still have no access to the information the 
Context Property should provide.

Please help me first by confirming or correcting my overall approach and if there are well known best practices available. Secondly please let me know how can I get information that the Context Property provides in the Hub and generally where this information is available and how to access and use them.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

'User' is a claims principle (normally stored in the asp cookie), to get the User form your Identity database use:

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

For future reference, your question is very long, you will get more help if you keep questions brief and to the point.

Comment: Thanks Tino, I did try to inject the identity manager in the Hub before but it did stopped the Hub from working for some reason. I think I'll do this by accessing the Hub functionality by it's instance from outside and see how I do. I'll certainly keep my questions shorter next time

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by using Authentication with SignalR. I don't need to add a user to any groups to push massages to them. In the Startup class I add Authentication above SignalR service and then the user object is passed to the Hub in the Context property. I can also push to any user by injecting the IHubContext to any class constructor I need.